# Properties.ListItem is null in ItemAdded event, while uploading documents using windows explorer(action menu) option in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, listitem

am generating a new unique id whenever a document is been uploaded in sharepoint. Am fetching the new ListItem using Properties.ListItem(SPItemEventProperties) and updating the new unique id value.

It works fine for documents created using upload option. where as the 'Properties.ListItem is null' when using the "Open with Windows Explorer" option under Action Menu in sharepoint 2007. Could anyone please suggest me on this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What does the "new unique id value" actually mean? It's some custom column?

Answer (score 1):

I think I've encountered this, and the solution was simply adding a null check - if the ListItem is null, don't continue the receiver.

The reason was that the receiver was then called again, and this time the ListItem was OK.

Comment: This worked for me. Sometimes we just assume ItemAdded will be having the list item, and forget the null check!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and fixed it by using the following work-around:

```
if (CurrentWeb.GetFile(properties.AfterUrl).Exists)
{
    CurrentListItem = CurrentWeb.GetFile(properties.AfterUrl).Item;
}
else if (CurrentWeb.GetFolder(properties.AfterUrl).Exists)
{    
    CurrentListItem = CurrentWeb.GetFolder(properties.AfterUrl).Item;
}
```

See [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointdevelopment/thread/8712648e-cf09-4f7b-ab13-1c6aacdf588a) link.